# mongodb , mongodb-shell , mongodb-compass

Tags: mongodb-compass

user@user-Lenovo-B490:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'mongodb-compass': No such file or directory

**dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'mongodb-compass'**: No such file or director